# Check time before execute sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query

```
select sum(netamount) 
from <table >
```

I need to add a condition before query to start execute: if the computer time is between 11 pm an 2 am and user clicks execute, run the query; else show message "wrong time"

Comment: Sounds great. Please share the basic research you did to find out how to accomplish this. "SQL find current time" and "SQL condition logic" would be two great google searches to do.

Comment: Use GETDATE() function to get current date with time and then check the time before query execution.

Comment: And don't tag two different database systems, it's either MySql or Sql-Server.

Comment: Instead of trying to add such logic to the query, *don't* allow users to run reporting queries on the live database. Create an agent job that calculates the data you want or better yet, moves the data to a reporting database. Schedule the job to run after hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting is a `RAISEERROR` to exit your code. Something like this...

```
if (datepart(hour,getdate()) >=23) or (datepart(hour,getdate()) <= 2)
begin
    raiserror('Report can not be run between 2300 and 0200',16,1)
    return
end

select sum (netamount) from SomeTable
```